# Leaflet D3js: Hexbin mouseover

Tags: javascript, d3.js, leaflet

I'm new in d3 and leaflet and starting from this project: http://bl.ocks.org/tnightingale/4668062
I would like to know if is possible to add a mouseover event on every hexagon? I'm trying to put:

```
d3.selectAll('.hexagon').on("mouseover", function(){console.log("mouse event")})
```

but with no effect.

thanks a lot

Comment: I have tried your code in the console on http://bl.ocks.org/tnightingale/raw/4668062/ and it works. Make sure you add it after the hexagons have been created.

Comment: see https://plnkr.co/edit/WLFpj5la795MDreroPa3?p=preview

Comment: ohh god now it's working!!  I do not know how but before I did the same thing but did't work, thanks!